# codeigniter returns 404 for everything inside subfolder

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

In my development environment (Mac OS, Apache, CI app inside a WP folder) my app works fine. Today I deployed it to server (Ubuntu Server, Apache, same CI app inside WP folder) and everything that I try return the 404 page.

This is my app/.htaccess:

```
SetEnv CI_ENV development

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

mod_rewrite is already enabled in this server.

In my config.php I've already tried:

```
 $config['base_url'] = 'http://server/app/';

 // problem in both situations
 $config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
 $config['index_page'] = '';
```

What is wrong here? When I go to http://server/app/index.php I get a 404 message. If I go to http://server/app/controller/action I also get a 404 message.

Comment: Is **app** web accessible? try to create `index.html` and check  Is it working as **http://server/app/index.html**

Comment: Also take a look at your virtual hosts file. You might need to create a config file for the url.

Comment: What is your site URL??

Comment: jagad89, I created http://server/app/phpinfo.php and it works fine.
abdulla, it is an intranet page.

Comment: What version of codeigniter are you using, If your using codeigniter 3.0 please check that all controllers and models **first letter is uppercase** example **Welcome.php** instead of **welcome.php** and model **Model_something.php**

Comment: wolfgang1983, you are right! This is really very confusing because in my development environment everything worked fine. I renamed the controllers

Answer (score 4):

Change this

In your `config.php`

1. `$config['base_url']    = '';`
2. `$config['index_page'] = '';`
3. `$config['uri_protocol']    = 'AUTO';`

then in `.htaccess`( ** this should be place out side of application folder ** )

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Read this as well

1. [Controllers](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html)
2. [Models](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html)
3. [Views](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html)

Comment: Did u place .htacess file as i mentioned??

Comment: Give me your site url

Comment: this solve the problem but now the views are not loading as expected.

Comment: Can you provide me your site URL??

Comment: if my answer helpful grateful by accepting it or Vote it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue. Just change the file permission to 644 to index.php
When I pull the changes via git. permission change to 664 so change back to 644. Hope this will solve issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the SetEnv . You can set the environment in the index.php file.

For the base_url, make sure it is the folder level that the index.php page is in.

/app/  should contain the application folder.

For the index_page, I would not set this to blank. Put it back to 'index.php';

Try this in your htaccess,

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yoursite.com [nc]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yoursite.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
 RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|js|img|css|application|robots\.txt)
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

You may not need to include the application folder in the RewriteCond but try it anyway.

make sure you default_contoller is set in your /config/routes.php file.

```
 $route['default_controller'] = "default_controller_here";
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved: 
I just discovered that controller's file must have names with capital letters.

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html